# Getting 2 mysql queries into one?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiplayer game site where a user get his list of games like this every 20 second:

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT gp.fk_game_id, gp.player_tiles, gp.infoPop, gp.chatbadge, g.lastdraw FROM ".$prefix."_gameplayer gp
                        INNER JOIN ".$prefix."_games g ON gp.fk_game_id = g.game_id
                    WHERE gp.fk_player_id = $currplayer AND g.invite=0 AND g.deleteby != $currplayer ORDER BY g.lastdraw ASC");  

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){

    $gameid = $row1['fk_game_id'];

    // GET CURRENT GAME OPPONENT ID AND BOARD DATA //
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT gp.fk_player_id
                              ,gp.last_draw_type
                              ,gp.player_turn
                              ,u.country
                              ,u.username
                              ,u.profileimg
                        FROM ".$prefix."_gameplayer gp
                            INNER JOIN ".$prefix."_users u
                                ON gp.fk_player_id = u.id
                         WHERE gp.fk_player_id!=$currplayer AND gp.fk_game_id=$gameid");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

If a player has 30 games it uses alot of resources due to the mysql_query inside the while loop.

Every game is stored in 2 db tables in 3 rows.

A games table row which holds the game data and 2 gameplayer tabnle rows, one for the current player and one for the opponent.

It is the row for the opponent which I have to run a second query for.

Is it possible to join this row into the first query so I only run one query every 20 seconds for a player?

The table schemas is as follows:

**Table games**
game_id - int(11) 
invitetime - timestamp 
lastdraw - timestamp 
timetodraw - datetime 
bag_tiles - text 
table_tiles - text 
new_tiles - text 
invite - int(11) 
random - int(11) 
active - int(11) 
finished - int(11) 
deleteby - int(11) 
warn1 - int(11) 
warn2 - int(11)

**Table gameplayer**
id - int(11) 
fk_game_id - int(11) 
fk_player_id - int(11) 
player_tiles - text 
player_draws - int(11) 
first_draw - int(11) 
player_turn - int(11) 
last_draw_type - int(11) 
player_passes - int(11) 
swapped - int(11) 
player_win - int(11) 
player_points - int(11) 
infoPop - int(11) 
chatbadge - int(11)

**Table users**
id - int(11) 
email - varchar(255) 
username - varchar(255) 
password - varchar(50) 
profileimg - varchar(25) 
country - int(11) 
register - date 
date - timestamp

Hope this makes sense and hoping for help :-)

Comment: Are you actually using those other columns from the first query, besides `fk_game_id` in code we can't see (later in the loop)?

Comment: Hi, can you show the schema definition please?

Comment: I have edited the post with the table schemas

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
 $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT gp.fk_player_id,gp.last_draw_type,gp.player_turn, u.country,u.username,u.profileimg,
                    gp.fk_game_id, gp.player_tiles, gp.infoPop, gp.chatbadge, g.lastdraw FROM ".$prefix."_gameplayer gp
                    INNER JOIN ".$prefix."_games g ON gp.fk_game_id = g.game_id 
                    INNER JOIN ".$prefix."_users u ON gp.fk_player_id = u.id
                    WHERE g.invite=0 AND g.deleteby != $currplayer 
                    AND gp.fk_game_id=$gameid ORDER BY g.lastdraw ASC");
```

Comment: This won't work because I don't get the second row in the gameplayer db with the opponents data...